# Encountered an internal AutoML error - PipelineRunException: No group keys passed

Tags: azure, automl

I have created pipeline using python sdk AutoML for data preparation, AutoML training and deploy as endpoint url with scheduler option. It was working as expected for past day. Today i tried to create new pipline at the AutoML model creation I got error

> PipelineRunException: No group keys passed!

Tried with different conda environment and also with new compute instance. Still that issue persist.

> "message": "Encountered an internal AutoML error. Error Message/Code: PipelineRunException. Additional Info: PipelineRunException:\n\tMessage: PipelineRunException: No group keys passed!\n\tInnerException: None\n\tErrorResponse \n{\n "error": {\n "message": "PipelineRunException: No group keys passed!"\n }\n}",
>
> "message_format": "Encountered an internal AutoML error. Error Message/Code: PipelineRunException. Additional Info: {error_details}"

what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

The azure team fixed this bug and released it for all regions. Now it's working as expected.